# Storyboard custom UITableviewcell selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

In my project I have custom `UITableview` cells, which happen to have a button in it. When this button is selected, it triggers a segue. In this segue I pass an object from the cell to the destination `UIViewcontroller`. I'm currently using the following code

```
else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Add"])
{
    SearchAddRecordViewController *addRecordViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    SearchCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.record);
    addRecordViewController.workingRecord = cell.record;
}
```

It turns out I'm passing null, because the button isn't triggering the selection of the cell, therefore no indexPathForSelectedRow. My question is, how do I get the indexpath for the cell which button has been pressed.

Edit:
Answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing a similar problem, this is how I was able to solve this.

I first created the implementation and header files for a UIButton subclass with the NSIndexPath property. I assigned the uibutton in the Storyboard the superclass of this new custom unbutton with the NSIndexPath property. I added the following code to the segue identification step (the key was realizing i could use the sender object as the source of triggering the segue):

```
else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Add"])
{
    SearchAddRecordViewController *addRecordViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    addRecordButton *button = (addRecordButton*) sender;
    NSIndexPath *path = button.indexPath;
    SearchCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    addRecordViewController.workingRecord = cell.record;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare an NSIndexpath variable in your custom cell's .h file and assign the indexPath to that variable in cellForRowAtindexPath. And Retrieve it and use it....Hope it will work

Comment: How will that help me? The issue is that I can't get any access to the cell from the button. The button triggers the segue, maybe I could use some kind of tag on the button? I don't know how I would make a dynamic tag with Storyboard though

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to determine the indexPath that avoids subclassing UIButton would be:

```
CGPoint point = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
```

EDIT:

I've factored this into a nice method you can add to a Category on UITableView:

```
-(NSIndexPath*)indexPathOfCellComponent:(UIView*)component {
    if([component isDescendantOfView:self] && component != self) {
        CGPoint point = [component.superview convertPoint:component.center toView:self];
        return [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the index path of the cell next in the table. Is their a away to decrement the path to get the proper one?

Comment: Sorry, the code was incorrect, I've corrected it now. `convertPoint` obviously needs to be called on the `button.superview` rather than directly on the button!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following manner, this helps you to uniquely identify which button is tapped and you can pass the appropriate values, I am just passing a string value for example

suppose **OutputString** is a string property in your destination view controller

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"]) {

    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    [segue.destinationViewController setOutputString:@"XYZ"];        
}
```

Comment: This makes some assumptions about your view hierarchy within the UITableViewCell which may not be true. See my answer using `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` for a more robust approach.